# PowerShell Exchange Online cmdlets return generic exceptions

Tags: powershell, exception, try-catch, exchange-server, powershell-cmdlet

My script adds users to an Exchange Online distribution group.

I want to catch the exception that tells me the user I am adding is already a member.

I want to seperately catch the exception that tells me the user I am adding doesn't exist.

It seems that the $error[0].Exception.GetType().FullName returns an exception of [System.Management.Automation.RemoteException] regardless of the actual error.

I assume this is an issue with running remote commands, is there a way around this?

```
$errorActionPreference = 'Stop'    

try 
{
    $group | Add-DistributionGroupMember -Member $member
}
catch [User.Does.Not.Exist.Exception] 
{
    Write-Host "$user is does not exist"
}
catch [User.Already.A.Member.Exception]
{
    Write-Host "$user is already a member"
}
catch
{
    Write-Host "terminating error"
}
```

Comment: Does the Add-DistributionGroupMember throw a terminating error or do you need to use the -ErrorAction Stop?

Comment: I should have mentioned, I am running the script with $errorActionPreference = 'Stop' which is the equivalent of -ErrorAction Stop on every command. I've updated my script extract.